# Swift Segue - while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated

Tags: ios, swift

The segue works fine when triggered outside the updatePassword func.

Full error -
'2020-07-03 13:17:34.656198+0100 FindingTaylorSwift[5305:154832] pushViewController:animated: called on <UINavigationController 0x7fc6a2037600> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.'

```
    @IBAction func updatePasword(_ sender: UIButton) {
.....
  
        _ = self.awsUserPoolUpdatePassword.updatePasswordWithConfirmationCodeError?
            .subscribe({ errorText in
                guard let elementContent = errorText.element?.localizedDescription else { return }

                switch elementContent {
                case "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AWSMobileClient.AWSMobileClientError error 2.)":
                    self.showAlert(title: UpdatePasswordError.titleCode, message: UpdatePasswordError.messageCode)
                case "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AWSMobileClient.AWSMobileClientError error 8.)":
                    self.showAlert(title: UpdatePasswordError.titlePassword, message: UpdatePasswordError.messagePasswordShort)
                case "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AWSMobileClient.AWSMobileClientError error 9.)":
                    self.showAlert(title: UpdatePasswordError.titlePassword, message: UpdatePasswordError.messagePasswordComplexity)
                default:
                    self.showAlert(title: UpdatePasswordError.titleDefault, message: UpdatePasswordError.messageDefault)
                }
            })

        _ = self.awsUserPoolUpdatePassword.updatePasswordWithConfirmationCodeResult?
            .subscribe({ resultText in
                guard let elementContent = resultText.element?.forgotPasswordState else { return }

                switch elementContent {
                case .done:
                    self.showAlert(title: PasswordUpated.title, message: "")
                    self.transitionToLogin()
                default:
                    self.showAlert(title: UpdatePasswordError.titleDefault, message: UpdatePasswordError.messageDefault)
                }
            })
    }

    private func transitionToLogin() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: AWSControllers.awsUpdatedPasswordSuccess, sender: self)
        }
//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: AWSControllers.awsUpdatedPasswordSuccess, sender: self)
//        }
    }
```

AWS Class

```
   internal func updatePasswordWithConfirmationCode(newPassword: String, confirmationCode: String) {

        guard let username = self.awsUserNameEmail else { return }

        let result = AWSMobileClient.default().rx.confirmForgotPassword(username: username, newPassword: newPassword, confirmationCode: confirmationCode)
            .materialize()

        result
            .compactMap { $0.element }
            .subscribe(onNext: { forgotPasswordResult in
                switch forgotPasswordResult.forgotPasswordState {
                case .done:
                    print("Password changed successfully")
                    self.userPasswordUpdateStatus = .passwordUpdateSuccessful
                default:
                    print("Error: Could not change password.")
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        updatePasswordWithConfirmationCodeError = result.compactMap { $0.error }
        updatePasswordWithConfirmationCodeResult = result.compactMap { $0.element }
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: AWSMobileClient {

    func signIn(username: String, password: String) -> Observable<SignInResult> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            self.base.signIn(username: username, password: password) { (signinResult, error) in
                if let signinResult = signinResult {
                    observer.onNext(signinResult)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observer.onError(error ?? RxError.unknown)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }

    func confirmForgotPassword(username: String, newPassword: String, confirmationCode: String) -> Observable<ForgotPasswordResult> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            self.base.confirmForgotPassword(username: username, newPassword: newPassword, confirmationCode: confirmationCode) { (confirmForgotPasswordResult, error) in
                if let confirmForgotPasswordResult = confirmForgotPasswordResult {
                    observer.onNext(confirmForgotPasswordResult)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observer.onError(error ?? RxError.unknown)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

The segue should only be triggered after a successful password update, the password updates successful which is confirmed by a print statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `showAlert` presents a UIAlertController, which is a kind of UIViewController...

If my guess is correct, then your problem is with these lines:

```
self.showAlert(title: PasswordUpated.title, message: "")
self.transitionToLogin()
```

You are trying to present two view controllers *at the same time*. You need to wait until the alert is finished presenting before attempting to present the next view controller, or more likely wait until the alert is finished being dismissed.

(This is not an RxSwift question.)

Comment: Thank you, I don't have enough IOS experience and I need to learn RX Swift